# Javascript getElementById show div hidden before end loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, delay, getelementbyid

I'm confused and tired of trying to make it work ... 
On one page, do a raffle (`select SQL`) and ride the `divs` (`style.display = none`) by echo (`PHP`). 
So far so good, each `DIV` with `ID`. 
I have a `BUTTON` that calls a Javascript function that will show the `DIV's`. Within this function, place a loop. But the browser only shows the `DIV` after traversing the loop, even working with the `setTimeout` function.

EX.

HTML:

```
<div id="1"> </div>
<div id="2"> </div>
<div id="3"> </div>
<div id="4"> </div>
<div id="5"> </div>
```

*NOTE: div id is creating depending rows `SQL SELECT`

```
<button Onclick="ShowDivs(<?php echo $numParticipants ?>)">Raffle</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
id=1;
function ShowDivs(participants) {
    do {
        window.document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        delay(1000); 
        alert(); // I need remove this alert
        id ++ ;
    } while (id<=participants);
} 

function delay(millis){
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = null;
        do { curDate = new Date(); }
        while(curDate-date < millis);
}
```

I need each DIV is displayed every 2 seconds. One by one every 2 seconds with a single click on the button Raffle.

Please can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery? It should make it easier, for what you are trying to do...

Comment: This question has been answered, check it out:



  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609139/how-to-show-and-hide-each-div-one-by-one-with-jquery

Comment: @user8133 In that question they are using JQuery, here not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because borswer can't process messages, so, you must use timeout for this issue

```
function Click() {
        ShowDivsTimer.start();
    }

    var ShowDivsTimer = {
        id: 1,
        timer: null,
        start: function() {
            this.timer = setInterval(this.process, 200);
        },
        stop: function() {
            if (this.timer != null) {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
                this.timer = null;
                this.id = 1;
            }
        },
        process: function() {
            var elem = document.getElementById(ShowDivsTimer.id);
            if (elem != null) {
                elem.style.display = "block";
                ++ShowDivsTimer.id;
            }
            else ShowDivsTimer.stop();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Your function will show ALL of the divs, in his code he asked for only a specific number.

Comment: It's just a sample. And we can change here only 2 lines ))
I just wanted to explain the root of this problem

Comment: Get it, very good and clear code (much better than mine). Just edited because you have forgot to initial the id in the stop function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval function:

```
<button Onclick="setInterval(ShowDivs(<?php echo $numParticipants ?>),2000)">
```

javascript:

```
id=0 //Use ids starting from zero!
function ShowDivs(numOfDivs) {
    window.document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    id++;
    if(id == numOfDivs)
        {
            clearInterval(showDivsInterval);
            id=0;
        }
}
```

More about setInterval: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: thanks for the reply, but is still not ok. The DIV's being displayed correctly but only when I click the button.

Comment: That's isn't what you want? If so, when do you want them to be displayed?

Comment: sorry I was not clear in explaining. 
Must click (once) on the raffle button, from there, the divs will be displayed one by one every 2 seconds according to the number of participants. 
Note: It's a raffle for teams in their respective groups for the championship.

Comment: @kernelpanic So what is wrong? After you click on the button, every 2 seconds another div will be shown, am I wrong? Are you saying that in my code you must keep clicking on the button? because it is not true...

Comment: thanks again, you guys are geniuses! 
I was trying to setInterval (less code) ... 
worked with the code "function click ()".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your delay function is a [busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), which causes the browser window thread to freeze. In all the browsers I know, it is the same thread that executes the javascript and renders the HTML. Since you clog the CPU with your busy wait the command, the command: `window.document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";` just updates the HTML or CSS, but the thread has no time to re-render the page...

As suggested by others, you should use intervals.